# Netbeans 8.1 won't make it past "Turning on modules" screen

Tags: java, 18.04, jdk, openjdk, netbeans

This week I installed netbeans 8.1 in my fresh ubuntu 18.04 installation.Prior to that I have installed jdk,jre and configured the JAVA_HOME variable.After trying to open netbeans I get the netbeans loading screen.However when the loading screen writes "Turning on modules" after a while netbeans will close.I've tried starting it through terminal but I get no errors.However I found this text files in my netbeans var folder

### messages.log

```
>Log Session: Tuesday, May 15, 2018 3:16:49 PM EEST
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 20180221-debian-8.1)
  Operating System        = Linux version 4.15.0-20-generic running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.8.0_171; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.171-b11; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_171-b11
  Java Home               = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_US (nb); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /home/mkcodergr
  Current Directory       = /home/mkcodergr/Documents/GitHub/eduonix-projects/blogapp
  User Directory          = /home/mkcodergr/.netbeans/8.1
  Cache Directory         = /home/mkcodergr/.cache/netbeans/8.1
  Installation            = /usr/share/netbeans/8.1/nb
                            /usr/share/netbeans/8.1/ide
                            /usr/share/netbeans/8.1/java
                            /usr/share/netbeans/8.1/apisupport
                            /usr/share/netbeans/8.1/harness
                            /usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/classes:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
  Application Classpath   = /usr/share/java/jcodings.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform/lib/boot.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/dt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform/core/org-netbeans-libs-asm.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform/core/core.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform/core/asm-all-5.0.1.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems-compat8.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/platform/core/core-base.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/nb/core/org-netbeans-upgrader.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/nb/core/locale/core_nb.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.internalInit(EquinoxLauncher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.init(EquinoxLauncher.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.netbinox.Netbinox.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.NetigsoHandle.turnOn(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(Unknown Source)
INFO [null]: Last record repeated again.
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Unknown Source)
INFO [null]: Last record repeated again.
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Netbeans 8.1 doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04 by Netbeans 8.2 can be installed by ubuntu-make with `umake ide netbeans` and it works in 18.04, but I don't think it's worth installing in Ubuntu 18.04 because the Eclipse snap package (*eclipse* Extensible Tool Platform and Java IDE) is a much better IDE for Java than Netbeans in 18.04.

Comment: I'am a student and my professor want us to use netbeans :(

Comment: Your professor and you will be happy to know that Netbeans 8.2 works in 18.04.

Comment: I will try it and will let you know

Comment: but why isn't it working on 18.04?

Comment: Netbeans 8.2 doesn't have any problem recognizing openjdk-11-jdk automatically in 18.04. Netbeans 8.1 does not recognize openjdk-11-jdk automatically in 18.04, and it does not recognize openjdk-8-jdk either, even when openjdk-8-jdk is selected as the default java.

Comment: I don't have jdk 11

Comment: openjdk-11-jdk isn't Java 11, it's just a funny package name in 18.04. I uninstalled it and tried opening Netbeans 8.1 with only openjdk-8-jdk installed and it didn't recognize openjdk-8-jdk either.

Comment: I tried umake ide netbeans but it throws segmentation fault

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77520/discussion-between-karel-and-manos-kounelakis).

Comment: @karel Can you post your upvoted comment as an answer so I can use this one as the dupe of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037055/netbeans-is-not-starting-on-ubuntu-18-04)? Please? Pretty Please???

Comment: @karel Yeah, read chat transcript; but OP has logged on 10 hours ago but didn't post an answer, so...  **:-)**

Comment: @Fabby sorry for being late :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest all of you read the chat that is posted on comments.I couldn't fix netbeans 8.1.What I did though was to download the latest version (8.2) from the site and install it using the bash script.However after opening netbeans 8.2 I couldn't create a new project.

Then I found the folowing stack overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476470/cant-create-project-on-netbeans-8-2

In summary what I have to do was to find my netbeans.conf file and change my java_home path

Go to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77520/discussion-between-karel-and-manos-kounelakis)

Comment: No worries: answer posted so upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently and deleting the cache folder didn't help.

So I fixed this issue by removing (after taking a backup) some of the recent modules created in the folder `$HOME/.netbeans/8.2/modules`.

Comment: The post is about 8.1 not 8.2